# Bosonic excitation investigated by scattering experiments in condensed matter physics

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, scattering-cross-section, bosons, raman-spectroscopy

Why experimental tools like Raman scattering, Inelastic neutron scattering (INS), Resonant inelastic X-ray scattering (RIXS), etc., can only detect **bosonic excitation**?
Why electronic excitation won't involve in these processes?
Its common feature is that they are photon-in photon-out spectroscopic techniques. But I still can not figure it out.